# Apple Developer app portal can longer generate new Bundle Seed ID

Tags: ios

The new interface in iOS developer portal no longer has the Generate New button for your app ID.  In its place is a "Use Team ID", which will result in the same seed ID being used.  Anyone has any idea why the change and what you should do to use a new bundle seed ID? Randomly make up some?

Comment: I m facing the same problem. Some recommends to use Team ID, but i m not sure whether i can use the same id for many apps.

Comment: Yes you can, and they will all be able to access the keychain.

Comment: We've tried to use the Team ID but we cannot submit the app as we get an error saying something like "This SKU is already is use".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generating new Seed IDs isn't possible anymore.

See: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ApplicationDevelopmentOverview/ConfigureYourProject/ConfigureYourProject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011186-CH6-SW8

> (...)
>   An app ID is a string containing two parts, a bundle seed ID and a bundle ID search string, with a period (.) separating the two parts. Each part of an app ID has different and important uses for your app.
>
> The bundle seed ID is a unique 10-character string generated by Apple. The bundle seed ID is what associates an app ID with a specific team. Apps that share the same bundle seed ID can also share keychain data, such as user names and passwords. Each development team is assigned a specific seed ID, known as the team ID. You should almost always use the team ID in any new apps you create; if you are doing Mac OS X development, using the team ID is your only option for the bundle seed ID, and it is provided automatically by the tools.
>   #
>   Note: If you have been already been developing apps for iOS, you may have previously created bundle seed IDs for apps you have already distributed. The ability to create new seed IDs has been removed from the tools, but you may use a previously created bundle seed ID instead of using your team ID. Do this only if you need the new app to share an existing app’s keychain data. Otherwise, use the team ID.
>   (...)

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 4):

I find this from ios developer library page, it's said:

> Choose a bundle seed ID from the pop-up menu. Use the team ID unless
>   you have an existing app (with a different bundle seed ID) that needs
>   to share data

For further details, you could refer to http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs/CreatingandConfiguringAppIDs.html

Comment: The link is dead now.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed the same thing.  I've contacted Apple Developer support and they don't seem to know anything about the provisioning profile.  There is no mention of any change to the provisioning portal, or on the developer forums.

I'm currently waiting on a response from Apple.  I'll give you an update if/when I find some sort of resolution.